# Xamarin Forms -> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for [Interface]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am receiving this error when using the Dependency Service on a Xamarin.Forms. I have seen answers to this error that involve iOS and the Linker. However, I am running this on Android and the Linker is off.

The constructor it is telling me it cannot find the default constructor for the Interface in the PCL.

I have been searching and debugging this for hours. What are some things that could be causing this error? I am pretty sure my DependencyService Implementations are correct so I feel like it is something different.

Here is my related code.

**Android**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(TextRecognition))]
namespace DiabetesAPP.Droid
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    [Activity(Label = "TextRecognition", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class TextRecognition : AppCompatActivity, ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor, ITextRecognition
    {
        private SurfaceView cameraView;
        private TextView textView;
        private CameraSource cameraSource;
        public string Resultados;
        private const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            cameraView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surface_view);
            textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtview);

            TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
            if (!textRecognizer.IsOperational)
            {
                Log.Error("Main Activity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
            }
            else
            {
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, textRecognizer)
                    .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                    .SetRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .Build();

                cameraView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                 textRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
            }

            Android.Widget.Button logonButton = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.button_send);
            logonButton.Click += LogonButton_Click;
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                        {
                           cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
        {

        }

        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
                {
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
                }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
           cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            cameraSource.Stop();
        }

        public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
            if (items.Size() != 0)
            {
                textView.Post(() =>
                {
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); i++)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append(((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value);
                        strBuilder.Append("\n");
                    }
                    textView.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
                    Resultados = strBuilder.ToString();
                });
            }
        }

        private void LogonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello from " + Resultados, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            //Intent data = new Intent(this, typeof(TextRecognition));
            //SetResult(Result.Ok, data);
            //// MessagingCenter.Send((DiabetesAPP.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);
            //// MessagingCenter.Send<DiabetesAPP.App, string>(DiabetesAPP.App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);
            //MessagingCenter.Send((DiabetesAPP.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);
            Toast.MakeText(this, Resultados, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);


            Finish();
        }

        public void Release()
        {

        }

        public void LaunchActivityInAndroid()
        {
            Activity activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
            var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(TextRecognition));
            activity.StartActivity(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            switch (resultCode)
            {
                case Result.Ok:
                    break;
            }

            Finish();
        }



        public interface ITextRecognition
        {

        }

//Update code - 16/09/2020
        public TextRecognition()
        {

        }


    }
}
```

**Implementation in a Xamarin.Form Page**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ITextRecognition))]
namespace DiabetesAPP.Views.FoodMenu
{

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FoodMenu : ContentPage
    {
        public FoodMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void Food_ManualEntry(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchFood());
        }

        public void Food_CameraEntry(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ITextRecognition>();
            DependencyService.Get<ITextRecognition>().LaunchActivityInAndroid();

        }

        public interface ITextRecognition
        {
            void LaunchActivityInAndroid();
        }

    }
}
```

**Error: System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type DiabetesAPP.Views.FoodMenu.FoodMenu+ITextRecognition**

What is going wrong?

Comment: what happens if you just add an empty constructor to your TextRecognition class?

Comment: @SomeStudent nothing...same error

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly what the error says it is.  For `DependencyService` to instantiate a class, the class **MUST** have a default (empty) constructor.  Yours does not.

Comment: That was the solution that SomeStudent gave me above...it didn't work :( I updated my code

Comment: why are you calling Register in FoodMenu?  FoodMenu is not the implementation class for ITextRecognition.

Comment: i thought i had to call it...but i removed and it gives the same error

Comment: you also have your `[Assembly]` attribute in the wrong place - it belongs in the class that is implementing the interface

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new `ITextRecognition` interface in `Android` project, you should use the interface which you created in the `Xamarin.forms` projet.

Also, it's better not to create the interface inside the FoodMenu class.

Here is the code example:

In Xamarin.Forms:

```
namespace App384
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FoodMenu : ContentPage
    {
        public FoodMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Food_CameraEntry(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ITextRecognition>();
            DependencyService.Get<ITextRecognition>().LaunchActivityInAndroid();

        }
    }

    public interface ITextRecognition
    {
        void LaunchActivityInAndroid();
    }
}
```

In Xamarin.Android project:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(TextRecognition))]
namespace App384.Droid
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    [Activity(Label = "TextRecognition", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class TextRecognition : AppCompatActivity, ITextRecognition
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public void LaunchActivityInAndroid()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LaunchActivityInAndroid");
        }

    }
}
```

I have uploaded [test demo here](https://github.com/XfHua/Dependency-Service) and you can check.

Refer: [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)