# xamarin forms mvvm Missing default constructor for

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have create a MessageCenterService interface

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    Task Toasting(string title);
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public async Task Toasting(string title)
    {
        using (var Dialog = UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(title, null))    
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying dependency inject but:

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IDialogService _dialogService;

    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        LoginCommand = new Command(Login);  
    }
}
```

**Erro => Missing default constructor for "..LoginViewModel"**

LoginPage.xaml

```
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:LoginViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

But if I put:

```
public LoginViewModel(){}

public LoginViewModel(IDialogService dialogService) //:Base() :this
{
    _dialogService = dialogService;
    ...
}
```

Error disappear but **IDialogService** never is instantiate **_dialogService** always null

LoginPage.xaml.cs changes not working too..

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public LoginPage(IDialogService dialogService): base()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I am missing something? Thanks in advance

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48009/pop-display-alert-message-from-viewmodel
[Missing Default Constructor error in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839032/missing-default-constructor-error-in-xamarin-forms)
[Xamarin Forms -> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for [Interface]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920361/xamarin-forms-system-missingmethodexception-default-constructor-not-found-fo)
[Missing Default Constructor error in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839032/missing-default-constructor-error-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the DependencyService or 3rd party libraries like TinyIOC.
Here is my sample code using the DependencyService.
You can register your service using DependencyService.Register<>() and simply invoke it using DependencyService.Get<>();

App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
   ...
   DependencyService.Register<DialogService>();
   ...
}
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
LoginPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
private IDialogService _dialogService;

public LoginViewModel()
{
   ...
   _dialogService = DependencyService.Get<DialogService>();;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;`

Comment: _dialogService continue null

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.